# $f(x)=e^x(x^2-5x+7)$.Prove $f^{(n)}(x)$ has 2 roots for any $n\in\mathbb N^*$. $f^{(n)}(x)$ means derivative of order n.

Tags: derivatives, proof-writing, induction, exponential-function, discriminant

$f(x)=e^x(x^2-5x+7)$.Prove $f^{(n)}(x)$ has 2 roots for any $n\in\mathbb N^*$. $f^{(n)}(x)$ means derivative of order n.

I am really confused by this exercise. I have calculated first 10 derivatives and $\Delta$ for each to see if it is positive, and it is indeed. I thought that by doing this eventually I will be able to find a general form for the derivative of order n and then prove it is right by mathematical induction then calculate $\Delta$ and show it is >0. The **first** and **second** term are easy to find, first one never changes and second one is $(-5x+2*nx)$, but the **third** term changes based on the second and last terms of $f^{(n-1)}(x)$ so I am stuck here with this approach.

Thanks in advance to anyone trying to help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hint.

Let for $x^2+ax+b$ we have $a^2-4b>0$.

Thus, $$(e^x(x^2+ax+b))'=e^x(x^2+ax+b)+e^x(2x+b)=e^x(x^2+(a+2)x+a+b)$$
and we see that
$$(a+2)^2-4(a+b)=a^2-4b+4>0.$$

Now, use induction.

A full solution can be written so.

Easy to see that for all $n$ we can write $f^{(n)}$ in the following form: $$f^{(n)}(x)=e^x(x^2+a_nx+b_n).$$

Now, $$f'(x)=e^x(x-1)(x-2)$$ has two real root. It was a base of the induction.

Let $f^{(n)}(x)=e^x(x^2+a_nx+b_n)$ has two real roots.

Thus, $$a_n^2-4b_n>0.$$

We'll prove that $f^{(n+1)}$ has two real roots.

Indeed, $$f^{(n+1)}(x)=\left(e^x(x^2+a_nx+b_n)\right)'=e^x(x^2+a_nx+b_n)+e^x(2x+a_n)=$$
$$=e^x(x^2+(a_n+2)x+a_n+b_n).$$
Id est, $$a_{n+1}=a_n+2,$$ $$b_{n+1}=a_n+b_n$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$a_{n+1}^2-4b_{n+1}>0$$ or
$$(a_n+2)^2-4(a_n+b_n)>0$$ or
$$a_n^2-4b_n+4>0,$$ which is true by the assumption of the induction.

Thus, by the induction $f^{(n)}$ has two real roots for all $n\geq1$ and we are done!

Comment: I do not understand. I see what you are proving: that if a function's delta is positive then its derivative's delta will be too or in other words, if a functions has 2 roots then its derivative will have too. How will this apply to my function? I will still have to find a general form for the 3rd term when I formulate the induction's hypothesis, no? I appreciate your answer, it is just that I do not get it.

Comment: @Radu Gabriel The first derivative of our function has two real roots. It says that  $f^{(n)}$ has two real roots for all $n\geq1$.

Comment: I can see that. I am really bad at mathematical proofs of any kind, I am sorry if I am annoying you. I can see how your answer relates to my function, it is really clear to me that it is enough to know that the first derivative has two roots to tell that the derivative of order n has two roots as well, but I don't know how to write this 'mathematically', or in your words "use induction"

Comment: @Radu Gabriel OK. I'll write a full solution.

Comment: I appreciate your answer a lot. I do, however, have another question that I do not know how to phrase into another post of its own. $f^{(n)}(x)$ in this case can be calculated and its general formula is $f^{(n)}(x)=e^x(x^2+x(2n-5)+(n^2-6n+7))$. How can I figure that the last term is $(n^2-6n+7)$? I came across such exercises before and if I knew how to do it it would have been great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Radu Gabriel You can prove it by induction. But all this is not necessary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94240/discussion-between-radu-gabriel-and-michael-rozenberg).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a more "explicit" demonstration I believe you will appreciate this answer. Let $g(x)=x^2-5x+7$. We have 
\begin{align}
g^{(1)}(x)=& 2x-5\\
g^{(2)}(x)=& 2\\
g^{(3)}(x)=& 0\\
\end{align}
and 
$$
g^{(n)}(x)= 0 \quad \mbox{ for all } n\geq 3
$$
We will derive the function $f(x)=e^xg(x)$ successively until we find a pattern of recall and then verify the existence of roots for $f(x)=e^xg(x)$.

For $n=1$ we have
 $$
\begin{array}{rc rl}
f(x)=e^xg(x) & \implies &f^{(1)}(x)=&e^xg^{(1)}(x)+e^xg(x)
           \\
             &          &=          & e^x\Big(g(x)+g^{(1)}(x)\Big)
\end{array}
$$
For $n=2$ we have
 $$
\begin{array}{rc rl}
f^{(1)}(x)=e^x\Big(g(x)+g^{(1)}(x)\Big) & \implies &f^{(2)}(x)=&e^x\Big(g(x)+g^{(1)}(x)\Big)
\\
                                 &&&+e^x\Big(g^{(1)}(x)+g^{(2)}(x)\Big)
           \\
             &          &=          & e^x\Big(g(x)+2g^{(1)}(x)+g^{(2)}(x)\Big)
\end{array}
$$
For $n=3$ we have
 $$
\begin{array}{rc rl}
f^{(2)}(x)=e^x\Big(g(x)+2g^{(1)}(x)+g^{(2)}(x)\Big)
& 
\implies 
&f^{(3)}(x)=&e^x\Big(g(x)+2g^{(1)}(x)+g^{(2)}(x)\Big)
\\
                                 &&&+e^x\Big(g^{(1)}(x)+2g^{(2)}(x)\Big)
           \\
             &          &=          & e^x\Big(g(x)+3g^{(1)}(x)+3g^{(2)}(x)\Big)
\end{array}
$$
For $n=4$ we have
 $$
\begin{array}{rc rl}
f^{(3)}(x)=e^x\Big(g(x)+3g^{(1)}(x)+3g^{(2)}(x)\Big)
& 
\implies 
&f^{(4)}(x)=&e^x\Big(g(x)+3g^{(1)}(x)+3g^{(2)}(x)\Big)
\\
&           &&+e^x\Big(g^{(1)}(x)+3g^{(2)}(x)\Big)
           \\
             &          &=          & e^x\Big(g(x)+4g^{(1)}(x)+6g^{(2)}(x)\Big)
\end{array}
$$
For $n=5$ we have
 $$
\begin{array}{rc rl}
f^{(4)}(x)=e^x\Big(g(x)+4g^{(1)}(x)+6g^{(2)}(x)\Big)
& 
\implies 
&f^{(5)}(x)=&e^x\Big(g(x)+4g^{(1)}(x)+6g^{(2)}(x)\Big)
\\
&           &&+e^x\Big(g^{(1)}(x)+4g^{(2)}(x)\Big)
           \\
             &          &=          & e^x\Big(g(x)+5g^{(1)}(x)+10g^{(2)}(x)\Big)
\end{array}
$$
For $n=6$ we have
 $$
\begin{array}{rc rl}
f^{(5)}(x)=e^x\Big(g(x)+5g^{(1)}(x)+10g^{(2)}(x)\Big)
& 
\implies 
&f^{(6)}(x)=&e^x\Big(g(x)+5g^{(1)}(x)+10g^{(2)}(x)\Big)
\\
&           &&+e^x\Big(g^{(1)}(x)+5g^{(2)}(x)\Big)
           \\
             &          &=          & e^x\Big(g(x)+6g^{(1)}(x)+15g^{(2)}(x)\Big)
\end{array}
$$
For  $A_1=1$ e $B_1=0$ set 
$$
A_{k+1}=A_k+1 \quad \mbox{ and } \quad B_{k+1}= A_{k}+B_{k}
$$
and note that 
$$
A_{k}=k \quad \mbox{ and } \quad B_{k}= A_{k-1}+\ldots+A_1= \frac{k(k-1)}{2}
$$
Furthermore, by  pattern of recall above we can prove by induction that
\begin{align}
f^{(k)}(x)=& e^x\Big( g(x)+A_{k} \cdot g^{(1)}(x)+B_{k}\cdot g^{(2)}(x) \Big)\\
          =& e^x\Big( (x^2-5x+7)+A_{k} \cdot(2x-5)+B_{k}\cdot 2 \Big)\\
          =& e^x\Big( x^2+(-5+2A_{k})x+(7-5A_k+2B_k)\Big)\\
          =& e^x\Big( x^2+(-5+2k)x+(7-5k+k(k-1))\Big)\\
           =& e^x\Big( x^2+(2k-5)x+(k^2-6k+7)\Big)\\
\end{align}
Now notice that the $f^{(k)}(x)$ function is null if and only if $\Big( x^2+(2k-5)x+(k^2-6k+7)\Big)$ is null. And the expression
$$
\Big( x^2+(2k-5)x+(k^2-6k+7)\Big)
$$ 
will have real raises if, and only if, its discriminant 
$$
(2k-5)^2-4(k^2-6k+7)
$$
is greater than zero. In fact we have,
$$
(2k-5)^2-4(k^2-6k+7)=14k-3>0 \quad \mbox{ for all } \quad k>0.
$$